# Audio.play() not working with iOS user agent

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari

I'm making a playlist app in react, where each `Track` component in the playlist has and `<audio>` element:

```js
const AudioPlayer = ({ track }: { track: Track }): JSX.Element => {
  const { src, title } = track;
  return (
    <audio id={"audio_" + title}>
      <source src={src} />
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
  );
};
```

In my redux store, when a user click a Track, I find the audio element associated with the track and use `audioElement.play()`:

```
const playTrack = (track: Track) => {
    //get all the audio elements for all the playlist tracks
    allAudioElems.current = tracks
      .map((t) => "audio_" + t.title)
      .map((id) => document.getElementById(id) as HTMLAudioElement)
      .filter((e) => e !== null);

    if (allAudioElems.current) {
      allAudioElems.current.forEach((element) => {
          //if the audio elements id matches the active track title, then play
        if (element.id === "audio_" + track.title) {
            element.play();
            setCurrentAudio(element);
        } else {
          element.pause();
        }
      });
    }
    setCurrentTrack(track.title);
    setIsPlayingAction(true);
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };
```

This all works fine on desktop for Chrome/Safari/Firefox, but fails on iOS Safari. Enabling `controls`, or `autoPlay` doesn't seem to do anything either.

I know that .play() returns a promise, but the error message is very vague when I catch the `.play()` error:

```
element.play().then((e)=>{
    console.log("played audio!");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
});
```

Gives Error:

```
Unhandeled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted
```

So what's one to do to get audio working on iOS?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez no, no solution yet